# Why is group_by() over multiple group and mutate giving me this error?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

So I have this data frame

```
               well day treatment stimulus animalid           name   value
1 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14 %prol. t-cells 0.00500
2 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14   %prol. tcrab 0.00370
3 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14 %prol. cd3+dn- 0.00067
4 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14      %prol. th 0.00100
5 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14    %prol. treg 0.00200
6 03-Well-A1.fcs   0      MOCK     MOCK      G14     %prol. ctl 0.00000
> str(test_valueadj)
'data.frame':   2160 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ well     : chr  "03-Well-A1.fcs" "03-Well-A1.fcs" "03-Well-A1.fcs" "03-Well-A1.fcs" ...
 $ day      : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","14","28",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 4 levels "HP","LP","MLV",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ stimulus : Factor w/ 4 levels "LP","HP","MOCK",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ animalid : Factor w/ 24 levels "B14","B15","B16",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ name     : Factor w/ 18 levels "% tcr-gd","%ctl",..: 7 8 5 9 10 6 3 4 18 17 ...
 $ value    : num  0.005 0.0037 0.00067 0.001 0.002 0 0.0013 0.00303 0.5 0 ...
```

I then want to subtract the value for each group_by(day,animalid,name) to my values for the other "treatment" value (Hp,LP,MLV)

```
test_valueadj<-test_valueadj%>%
  group_by(animalid,day,name)%>%
  mutate(adjusted = (filter(treatment!="MOCK")$value)-(filter(treatment=="MOCK")$value))
```

I then get the following error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `adjusted`.
x no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
ℹ Input `adjusted` is `(filter(treatment == "HP")$value) - (filter(treatment == "MOCK")$value)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: animalid = "B14", day = "0", name = "% tcr-gd".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have done a similar operation before and it worked fine but cannot pin point what's causing this issue.

Thank you for the help

Comment: does something like this work?... `mutate(adjusted = (value[treatment!="MOCK"])-(value[treatment=="MOCK"]))`

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I tried that ```mutate(adjusted = test_valueadj[treatment!="MOCK"]$value- test_valueadj[treatment=="MOCK"]$value) ``` and i got another error ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `adjusted`.
x Input `adjusted` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `adjusted` is `-...`.
ℹ Input `adjusted` must be size 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: animalid = "B14", day = "0", name = "% tcr-gd".```

Comment: You need to summarize something at group by, your code is currently returning multiple values breaking the structure of tibble just take the max value or the sum `mutate(adjusted = max(value[treatment!="MOCK"])) - max(value[treatment=="MOCK"]))`

Comment: But in my initial function every group should one single value in my filter function. I tried your solution but it doesn't work either, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: A question. You say that "I then want to subtract the value for each group_by(day,animalid,name) to my values for the other "treatment" value (Hp,LP,MLV)". Does it mean that for each group (day x animalid x name) there are just 2 observations, one with `treatment=="MOCK"` and the other with `treatment != "MOCK"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to `filter()` do not have a `data.frame` object matched to their `.data` formal argument.

When you "pipe into" a function call by using the `magrittr` pipe infix operator `%>%`, the pipe constructs a new function call that is based on the function call on the RHS of the pipe (i.e, the `rhs` formal argument to the pipe). The pipe either implicitly or explicitly supplies the value of the LHS expression (the `lhs` argument) as an argument to one of the RHS function's formal operators, depending on whether the symbol `.` is supplied by the user as a whole argument to the `rhs` function call. It will also substitute `lhs` for any occurrence of the symbol `.` within user supplied arguments to the `rhs` call.

The value of `.data` in any dplyr verb that has been piped to (i.e., that is the `rhs` argument to the pipe function,) will be matched to the value of the `lhs` formal argument to the pipe function,  long as the value of `.data` is not otherwise specified by the user by providing it as a named argument.) Your function calls to `filter()` occur *within* the arguments to `mutate()`. They are not the `rhs` argument to the function call `%>%`, they just **occur within the `rhs` argument** to `%>%`. The pipe will NOT recursively construct new function calls from function calls that are supplied as arguments to the function that the pipe is modifying. The pipe is not going to try to supply the LHS object to them as an argument unless you explicitly provide it by specifying that the value of .data should be the symbol `.`, either positionally or by name.

`adjusted = (filter(treatment!="MOCK")$value)-(filter(treatment=="MOCK")$value)` is an argument that you are providing to the `mutate()` function, which is the `rhs` argument to the pipe function. The enclosing pipe function will substitute the value of `.` anywhere that `.` occurs in the arguments to the function call that constitutes the `rhs` argument but it will not otherwise modify the arguments. That means the pipe will NOT try to implicitly supply the value of the `lhs` argument as an argument to the calls to `filter()` that occur within this argument.

You are getting an error about logical values because e.g. your call to
`filter(treatment!="MOCK")` is evaluated as `filter(.data = treatment!="MOCK")`, not as `filter(.data = ., treatment != "MOCK")`. There is only one argument supplied to filter so it gets positionally matched to the first formal argument, which is `.data`. `treatment!="MOCK"` evalutes to a logical value, so you get your error, because there is no S3 method `filter.logical`. You would need to express it as `filter(., treatment!="MOCK")` in order for these function calls to be able access the `data.frame` object being piped in.

In any case, using `dplyr` verbs in arguments to other dplyr verbs will almost always yield code that is extremely hard to reason about. There's a reason you never see this performed in the `dplyr` vignettes. This kind of operation also can't be performed against a `dbplyr` SQL backend.

You should consider performing a join instead. I don't have full insight into the structure of your data but it seems like there are only one MOCK record per group? if so something like this is safe:

```
test_test_valueadj_MOCK <- filter(test_valueadj, treatment == "MOCK") %>%
  select(animalid, day, name, value)

test_test_valueadj_NONMOCK <- filter(test_valueadj, treatment != "MOCK") 

test_valueadj <- left_join(
  test_test_valueadj_NONMOCK,
  test_test_valueadj_MOCK,
  by = c(animalid, day, name),
  suffix = c("", "_mock")
) %>%
  mutate(adjusted = value_mock - value)
```

Note that it is not necessary to perform grouping in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the help! Would this work with merge as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use `base::merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If I undersant well that "I then want to subtract the value for each group_by(day,animalid,name) to my values for the other "treatment" value (Hp,LP,MLV)" implies that for each group there are just two observations, one with `treatment=="MOCK"` and the other with `treatment!="MOCK"`, then an approximation would be:

```r
test_valueadj %>%
    mutate(dich_treatment = if_else(treatment != "MOCK", "NMOCK", "MOCK")) %>%
    group_by(animalid,day,name) %>%
    arrange(dich_treatment) %>%
    mutate(adjusted = lag(value) - value) %>%
    filter(treatment != "MOCK")
```